# How to push perforce depo to github?

Tags: git, github, perforce

I was trying to migrate a depot with all the submit history from perforce to GitHub and only use GitHub for my future work. However, after I clone the perforce depot to the git repo, I can't push my git repo to GitHub.

The steps I have taken are:

1. I create a new empty folder as myGitRepoDir
2. Use git p4 to clone perforce depot
   The command I used: `git p4 clone //myP4depot/@all to a local folder`
   and git p4 showed me:

> ```
> Initialized empty Git repository in C:/dev/myGitRepoDir/.git
> Importing from //myP4depot/@all into mygitRepoDir
> Import destination: refs/remotes/p4/master
> ```

3. After the clone finished I checked git remote -v, and it shows:

> ```
> origin  https:// github.com/ myGitHubAccount / myGitRepoDir.git (fetch)
> origin  https:// github.com/ myGitHubAccount/ myGitRepoDir.git (push)
> ```

4. I created an empty repo on GitHub, name it myGitRepoDir, and followed the instruction on Github to push an existing repository from the command line

> ```
> git remote add origin https://github.com/dearfuture-dev/DearFuture.git
> git branch -M main 
> git push -u origin main
> ```

After this step.
I got an error saying:

> ```
> $ git push origin main
> Enumerating objects: 61372, done.
> Counting objects: 100% (61372/61372), done.
> Delta compression using up to 12 threads
> Compressing objects: 100% (40669/40669), done.
> error: RPC failed; curl 56 OpenSSL SSL_read: Connection was aborted, errno 10053
> send-pack: unexpected disconnect while reading sideband packet
> Writing objects: 100% (61372/61372), 7.78 GiB | 17.19 MiB/s, done.
> Total 61372 (delta 20500), reused 61372 (delta 20500), pack-reused 0
> fatal: the remote end hung up unexpectedly
> Everything up-to-date
> ```

I'm using windows OS, and my git is up to date.
I already tried to increase http.postBuffer size, it didn't work.
I also tried to downgrade http.version to HTTP/1.1, it didn't work either.

What should I do to fix this error?

I noticed my .git folder is 7.79GB, which is pretty close to 7.78 after the error message. Does .git folder have anything to do with this issue?

Comment: GitHub does have a limit for repository sizes(I think 2GB). That might be the problem.

Comment: Oh, I didn't know there's a size limit for a repository. I will do some research on it

Comment: You just should not (a) store big files in git and (b) store binary files in git.

Comment: I checked the docs, GitHub doesn’t allows a push greater than 2GB. I noticed in .git folder, there’s a .pack file, and it’s like 7.7GB, I assume this pack file is the reason. But I tried to repack it, make the max size for a .pack file to 1GB, and push. It didn’t work. The project I cloned from perforce is a game project, so it does have some large files but I checked in the project there’s no other one single file greater than 2GB. Sorry, I’m pretty new to git and GitHub. I cloned the repo from perforce, I don’t know how can I pick large files out without messing up the submit history

Comment: If you want to remove an already pushed file, you need to mess up the history and force push. This is why you should not commit those from the beginning.

Comment: After I used git p4 to clone the depot from perforce, I haven’t managed to push anything. The repo on GitHub is still empty.